# Mips sll weird behaviour

Tags: mips, qtspim

My `$t4` was originally `4`.
[image]

I thought `sll` by `2` is suppose to times `4`, which should make my `t4=16`.
[image]

But apparently the result is `10`, why is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out QtSpim shows values in hex. I am deeply frustrated with myself.